# Can "consider" always replace "take into account" in scientific writing?

Tags: science, scientific-language

Consider these two instructions to a science problem:

> Calculate the velocity. Consider the effect of air resistance.

> Calculate the velocity. Take into account the effect of air resistance.

For me, these instructions do not have the same meaning. I understand the first instruction as: "Think about the effect of air resistance. If it its effect on velocity is negligible, ignore it, but if it is significant, include it in the calculation.", while I understand the second instruction as: "Regardless of whether air resistance's effect on velocity is negligible, include it in the calculation."

It is interesting that both the AI writing assistant and real English editors consistently replace **every** instance of "take into account" with "consider".  But I never get an explanation for the substitution.

On the other hand, I found the following text in the article [What is the meaning of "consider" & "take into account" in ISO 14001:2015](https://emsmastery.com/2021/01/27/what-is-the-meaning-of-consider-take-into-account-in-iso-140012015/):

> The word "consider" means it is necessary to think about the topic but it can be excluded; whereas "take into account" means it is necessary to think about the topic but it cannot be excluded.

So I would like to know from native speakers of English, possibly with a **scientific background**, whether both formulations have the same meaning and whether and **why** is one of them better.

Comment: In my opinion, the problem could be that "consider" has a much broader meaning than "take into account"; something like "while"/"whereas" pair.

Comment: What AI writing assistant? Which editors?

Comment: @alphabet InstaText / Scribendi.

Comment: The ISO link differentiates them clearly.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I am aware of that.  But when I answered with this citation to another question on english.SE, I was downvoted and commented "That may be an arbitrary distinction in an ISO document but it doesn't reflect how they're used by normal people in regular English."

Comment: @Lambie As far as I understand JD's answer, he said they are equivalent, except for "EMS community". So as I see things, your comment is almost diametrically opposite to his answer. I therefore invite you to provide your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Merriam-Webster, "to take into account"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20into%20account) is an idiomatic synonym for consider. The definition listed is:

> : to give attention or consideration to (something)

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/take-into-account) is essentially the same definition:

> to consider or remember something when judging a situation:

I reviewed the article you listed "What is the meaning of “Consider” & “Take into account” in ISO 14001:2015?" and what is occurring here is that the definition is being interpreted within the framework of a standard. As such, the interpreting is drawing a technical distinction not present in standard usage. To wit:

> ISO 14001 uses the word “consider” and the phrase “take into account” with a specific intent... The word “consider” means it is necessary to think about the topic but it can be excluded; whereas “take into account” means it is necessary to think about the topic but it cannot be excluded.

This is a [precising distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precising_definition) which creates a technical distinction for use in a particular language community. This distinction doesn't exist in the general usage, but is declared ostensibly on utilitarian ground for people in the EMS community, which seems to be some sort of environmental organization. Meanings of words are not objective or fixed, but rather are a function of the people who decide to use them. So, if you are working with the ISO standard, then there is a distinction, however, if you are not, then generally there is not.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Does this mean that in your opinion, apart from the above-mentioned ISO, both formulations are equivalent and neither of them is to be preferred?

Comment: So, there is the old joke about "a spherical cow in a vacuum" where a physics or engineering problem is formulated without thought of air resistance or the impact of different facets of a cow on the velocity. IMO, either would be suggesting that the spherical cow is not in a vacuum. but if one were to include that feature and then discount it (i.e. "consider") wouldn't the result be wrong? Or at least wouldn't you need to do it both ways?

Comment: @Pygmalion I believe that in common speech both are strong synonyms, and in writing, it's better to use one literal word than three words in an idiom. But I'm a fan of Strunk and White.

Comment: +1 for "This distinction doesn't exist in the general usage..."

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible that the effects are non-existent or so negligible as to be truly *de minimis*, and the person writing the instructions has no desire to be a prick and give their students a tough time, there should be the phrase **effects, if any**. It has nothing to do with the choice of **consider** vs **take into account**, which are for all intents and purposes synonymous. Absent such a qualification, the reader will reasonably infer that there will be some effects, and that they will not be so negligible as to be an utter waste of time to *consider* or to *take into account*.